# Nothing gets saved on .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

When I make any change in .htaccess file of my WordPress site for [Mosaic Adventure](https://mosaicadventure.com), nothing gets saved.

I came across this page which says that my site might be hacked - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185638/how-to-stop-wordpress-from-changing-default-htaccess-permissions-to-444/191570#191570

I have already used security plugin to do scan but problem is not solved yet.

Can anyone please let me know what is the best way to solve this issue?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: How are you making the changes to .htaccess? Through FTP? Are you getting any errors when saving the file? How do you know it's not saving?

Comment: Hi Tim, We do that through CPANEl. When we update, it just don't show any message and seems updated. But there is no change when we check that again.